# Install Wiley's Lato fonts onLinux

Tags: fonts, linux, installing-fonts

I would like to use the LaTeX class provided by the editor Wiley to write a scientific article. Everything works well, except the Lato fonts used by this class: some of them are not available on my computer, and are replaced by quite ugly-looking fonts.

The fonts provided by Wiley are available [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/10991212/APA-lato-1509470432000.zip), in the folder `lato-fonts`. There is a Windows installer for those fonts, but unfortunately no instruction at all for Linux users (I'm under Linux Manjaro, with TeXLive 2020).

Installing the Manjaro package `ttf-lato` was unhelpful. I also tried those instructions from the `lato-fonts` folder, but they did not help:

```
sudo cp lato.sty /etc/texmf/tex/generic/misc/
sudo cp *.ttf /usr/share/fonts/TTF/
sudo texhash
```

Is there any proper way to install those Lato fonts "by hand"?

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no these are type1 fonts, with lots of tfm, vf etc, but sadly no tds structure. So the instruction is "put everything in the right place ;-)"

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I doubt that it will work with this class.

Comment: Indeed, it did not work ;) I'm currently struggling to find the right place for each of those files (e.g. using this: https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html#fndb), but I'm still far from a solution. (And, sadly, now the unfound fonts are not simply replaced by standard fonts: there are blocking compilation errors.)

Comment: There is a `Makefile` with an `install` target, that seems to generate a TDS in `$TEXMFHOME` and copy all the fonts in the right places. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I also get an error using the makefile (`rm -f -r lato
make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « lato-drv.tex », nécessaire pour « lato-rec.tex ». Arrêt.`). Don't know if this is due to my local setup, or if the makefile itself is outdated...

Comment: Move the tfm,pfb,vf,fd, sty,map files to your texmfhome into suitable subfolders, e.g. the tfm should go to `/fonts/tfm/lato`, check texmf-dist to guess the folders, normally it is quite obvious., add `\pdfmapfile{=lato.map}` to your document and try if it works.

Comment: It worked! ;) You can add this as an answer if you wish, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @Ulrike Fischer's answer, I tried to guess the right place for each type of file. For me, the following worked, and allowed a proper compilation of the .tex document:

```
# Make local directory:
mkdir ~/texmf/ -p

# .tfm files:
mkdir ~/texmf/fonts/tfm/lato/ -p
cp *.tfm ~/texmf/fonts/tfm/lato/

# .afm files:
mkdir ~/texmf/fonts/afm/lato/ -p
sudo cp *.afm ~/texmf/fonts/afm/lato/

# .pfb files:
mkdir ~/texmf/fonts/type1/lato/ -p
cp *.pfb ~/texmf/fonts/type1/lato/

# .vf files:
mkdir ~/texmf/fonts/vf/lato/ -p
cp *.vf ~/texmf/fonts/vf/lato/

# .fd files:
mkdir ~/texmf/tex/latex/lato/ -p
cp *.fd ~/texmf/tex/latex/lato/

# .sty file:
cp *.sty ~/texmf/tex/latex/lato/

# .map file:
mkdir ~/texmf/fonts/map/fontname -p
cp *.map ~/texmf/fonts/map/fontname

# .etx files:
mkdir ~/texmf/tex/fontinst/latinetx/ -p
cp *.etx ~/texmf/tex/fontinst/latinetx/

# .mtx files:
mkdir ~/texmf/tex/fontinst/latinmtx/ -p
cp *.etx ~/texmf/tex/fontinst/latinmtx/

# .enc files:
mkdir ~/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lato -p
cp *.enc ~/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/lato

# Final config:
sudo texhash
sudo updmap-sys --force --enable Map=lato.map
sudo texhash
```

Just in case it would be useful for someone.